# Word for overusing superlatives and hyperbolic speech

Tags: single-word-requests

When the use of certain descriptors are continuously used exhaustively that continue to espouse the greatest, best, smartest, strongest, prettiest, etc etc always being the best of something, it is known as _______.

When a person continuously keeps using adjectives that describe something, someone, or themselves as always being the *insert superlative*.

Words that are, although flattering, actually so overwhelmingly 'over the top' and impossibly based in fact they are examples of _______.

Superlatives, hyperbole, and hyperbolical speech in the extreme!

What I am looking for is the general descriptor of the routinely repeated usage of this extremely over-exaggerated, hyperbolical speech found in one's daily communications.

(Exaggerating or diminishing beyond the fact; exceeding the truth; bordering on delusional)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Can you rephrase your question and provide a suitable title?

Comment: ...are you perhaps referring to the use of superlatives?  The descriptors along with comparatives that indicate when one thing is more (-er) or the most (-est) of something, as compared to another?  I'm not sure what else your question is asking, sorry, but even that bit of clarification might help.

Comment: Yeah, such terms are usually referred to as "superlatives".  Of course, they also tend to provoke a few less polite descriptions.

Comment: *Flamboyant*? pattern of speech

Comment: In the future, we will probably have the words *trumpism* or *trumpistry*.

Answer (score 2):

How about [**bombastic**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bombastic)?

> **bombastic** [adj] suggests language with a theatricality or staginess of style far too powerful or declamatory for the meaning or sentiment being expressed

It's often used describe flowery or overly complex language/word choice, but I could see it also applying to dramatic superlative-laden language as well.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all of the elements of your question and seeking a single word to describe, or name, a person who engages in such outrageous rhetoric, I suggest **gonzo**. It may not be perfect, but it sounds about right, kind of like **bonkers**.

From [*The Free Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gonzo):

> **gonzo** *adj Slang*: Using an exaggerated, highly subjective style; extreme, unconventional, or bizarre; crazy, excited, or unrestrained
>
> **gonzo** *adj*: wild or crazy
>
> **gonzo** *n*:  a wild or crazy person
>
> **gonzo** *adj Slang*: fiercely advocative or partial without regard for balance or objectivity
>
> **gonzo** *adj.*: conspicuously or grossly unconventional or unusual

Answer (score 0):

I think I should offer several possibilities.  I'll let you do the mixing and matching to fit your sentences.

*overdoing it*

*slightly hysterical*

*overstating*

*not understated* (this one is the understated choice!)

*over the top*

Example, what you might provide as feedback about a piece of student writing, or feedback to a friend about a letter draft:

> Please tone down your language.  You use so many *superlatives* [fantastic word contributed by others] that your letter ends up sounding a bit *hysterical*.  Aim for a neutral tone.